# PhpMyAdmin Import Errors Database

Tags: database, phpmyadmin

When im trying to upload a DB i get the following error!

345 errors were found during analysis.

> Unexpected character. (near ":" at position 230502) Unexpected
>   character. (near ":" at position 230504) Unexpected character. (near
>   "{" at position 230505) Unexpected character. (near ":" at position
>   230507) Unexpected character. (near ":" at position 230509) Unexpected
>   character. (near ":" at position 230518) Unexpected character. (near
>   ":" at position 230520) Unexpected character. (near ":" at position
>   230532) Unexpected character. (near ":" at position 230534) Unexpected
>   character. (near ":" at position 230544) Unexpected character. (near
>   ":" at position 230547) Unexpected character. (near ":" at position
>   230567) Unexpected character. (near ":" at position 230569) Unexpected
>   character. (near ":" at position 230581) Unexpected character. (near
>   ":" at position 230583) Unexpected character. (near ":" at position
>   230593) Unexpected character. (near ":" at position 230595) Unexpected
>   character. (near ":" at position 230609) Unexpected character. (near
>   "}" at position 230621) Unexpected character. (near ":" at position
>   230799) Unexpected character. (near ":" at position 230801) Unexpected
>   character. (near "{" at position 230802) Unexpected character. (near
>   ":" at position 230804) Unexpected character. (near ":" at position
>   230806) Unexpected character. (near ":" at position 230819) Unexpected
>   character. (near ":" at position 230821) Unexpected character. (near
>   ":" at position 230833) Unexpected character. (near ":" at position
>   230835) Unexpected character. (near ":" at position 230844)

I really don't know whats going on here!

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version are you using? How big is the SQL file you're importing?

Comment: Version: 4.5.5, file size: 663kb

Comment: That file size should generally be fine, but that phpMyAdmin version is a bit outdated. I'm not aware of any specific fixes for an issue like this but you could try upgrading. If you don't have any sensitive information in your .sql file you might try uploading to the demo server at https://demo.phpmyadmin.net as a test.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue; my import file was uncompressed so I went back and exported it gzipped and the import was fine.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. This solution worked and it would be really interesting to know the reason

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me as well. In my case it was the gzipped file from the export that was the problem. I downloaded the uncompressed file and gzipped it on my computer, now it works.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but the reason was that my .sql files was encoded utf16 and the default setting in PhpMyAdmin is utf8. When I changed it, the import worked.

Comment: Good find, for some reason even when specifying UTF8 in mysqldump (windows) it still exports it as utf-16

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same issue. But In my case, My DB is the corrupted one. So I took the Database again using the mysqldump command & import it, then it started working.

```
mysqldump -u root -p database_name > "/home/databasename.sql"
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste your DB file in "C:\xampp\mysql\bin"

then go to "CMD"

write

1. cd C:\xampp\mysql\bin
2. mysql -u root -p DB_name <db_file.sql
3. enter your DB password
4. enjoy